# PC goes to splash screen at startup because of GRUB setting

Tags: boot, grub2, plymouth

I made the following change in the grub file `/etc/default/grub`:

`DEFAULT=2`

Now, the my pc goes to the splash screen automatically on startup. How can I boot into Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

You still have the USB-stick/DVD that you used to install Ubuntu? Boot from this media. Than navigate to '

> etc/default/grub

and change `DEFAULT=2` back into `DEFAULT=0`.

That should get things back to function again.

You can also use a USB-stick/DVD with e.g. `AIO-SRT` or `Ikki-boot`, but changing back the default-setting is imo the best solution.

Comment: I booted from USB and changed ``DEFAULT=2`` back to ``DEFAULT=0``. But still have the same issue. I don't know whether issuing ``update-grub2`` is required.

Comment: I resintalled the Ubuntu